# Unpacking big list in python

Tags: python, list, sqlite, unpack

I have to unpack this big list and put every item into db.
Everything works well except these data.

I tried with :

```
([styles], [seasons], [day], [id]) = search_
```

but I get an error like this:

```
exception=ValueError('too many values to unpack (expected 4)')>
```

I use a query like this :

```
insert= "INSERT INTO cantina (styles,seasons,day,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
db.execute(insert,(styles,seasons,day,id))
```

I'm aware that I've made a mistake , but here there are 4 field for each row, seems right

```
search_ = [[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['01'], ['81535']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['02'], ['81536']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['03'], ['81537']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['04'], ['81538']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['05'], ['81539']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['06'], ['81540']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['07'], ['81541']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['08'], ['81542']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['09'], ['81543']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['10'], ['81544']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['11'], ['81545']],
[["Redwine"], ['04'], ['12'], ['81546']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['01'], ['97179']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['02'], ['97180']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['03'], ['97181']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['04'], ['97182']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['05'], ['97183']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['06'], ['97184']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['07'], ['97185']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['08'], ['97186']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['09'], ['97187']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['10'], ['97188']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['11'], ['97189']],
[["Redwine"], ['02'], ['12'], ['97190']]]

([styles], [seasons], [day], [id]) = search_

insert= "INSERT INTO cantina (styles,seasons,day,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
db.execute(insert,(styles,seasons,day,id))
```

EDIT :

Hi Barmar , because that list comes from another function by which  I join
four lists:

```
def cantina ( cantina_id)
  for ... in ...:
     styles = 
     season  = 
     day = 
     id = 
     result.append([[styles], [season], [day], [id]]])
  return result
```

and 'append' only accepts one parameter.

I have to process a few data, based on 'cantina_id';
add it to four lists and save them to db

Comment: There's no reason to put each value in its own list as you're doing in the `append` call. Just don't do that and use `executemany`.

Comment: You should use `result.append([styles, season, day, id])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over `search_` and process each row separately.

```
insert= "INSERT INTO cantina (styles,seasons,day,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
for row in search_:
    ([styles], [seasons], [day], [id]) = row
    cur.execute(insert,(styles,seasons,day,id))
db.commit()
```

If you change your `cantina` function so it doesn't create all those single-element lists, you could use `executemany()`

```
def cantina ( cantina_id)
  result = []
  for ... in ...:
     styles = 
     season  = 
     day = 
     id = 
     result.append([styles, season, day, id])
  return result

search_ = cantina(some_id)
insert= "INSERT INTO cantina (styles,seasons,day,id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
cur.executemany(insert, search_)
db.commit()
```